# Создание новых потоков внутри потока

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread, posix

Я новичок в pthread и стараюсь понять, как они работают. Цель написать программу, которая создает в `main` поток. Каждый новый созданный поток создает 2 новых потока. При этом потоки должны получать свой id и время для ожидания(от 1 до 10 секунд) в качестве параметров. Новые потоки создаются до тех пор, пока не достигнут максимума(определяется константой). В моей программе потоки создаются правильно. Проблема в том, что id не уникальны - каждый id выводится дважды. Например:

```
t0: Hello my id is 0
t2: Hello my id is 2
t2: Hello my id is 2
t4: Hello my id is 4
t4: Hello my id is 4
```

Я предполагаю, что проблема лежит в общем указателе на массив параметров, но я не знаю это предотвратить. Доступ к массиву я блокирую с помощью mutex и вроде как не должно быть race condition. Но все равно в результате id неверен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_THREADS 10

pthread_mutex_t threads_count_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t args_mutex;

int wait_time_overall = 0;
int threads_count = 0;

void* SpawnTwoThreads(void *args) {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;  

    int* thread_args =  (int*)args;
    printf("Sleeping for %d befor thread creation\n", thread_args[1]);
    sleep(thread_args[1]);
    printf("t%d: Hello, my id is %d\n", thread_args[0], thread_args[0]);
    if (threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);
            threads_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&args_mutex);
            thread_args[0]++;
            thread_args[1] = rand() % 10;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&args_mutex);
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, thread_args);
    }

    if (threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);    
           threads_count++;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex);

       pthread_mutex_lock(&args_mutex); 
           thread_args[0] = rand() % 10;
           thread_args[1]++;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&args_mutex);
       pthread_create(&t2, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, thread_args);
    }
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_mutex_init(&threads_count_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&args_mutex, NULL);

    int start_args[2];
    start_args[0] = 0;
    start_args[1] = rand() % 10;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, start_args);
    printf("In main: waiting for all threads to complete\n");
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("Overall waittime is %d\n", wait_time_overall);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, гонка все равно есть.

Здесь переменная читается

```
if (threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
```

а здесь пишется

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);    
    threads_count++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex);
```

да, чтение нужно также в мютекс заворачивать. Этой переменной ещё пару раз в коде не везет:).

Но вся проблема в том, что thread_args передается по указателю. А это похоже совсем не то, что Вы хотели. Достаточно перед созданием потока сделать копию этой структуры, как все стает на свои места. Плюс, похоже там есть копипаста в SpawnTwoThreads - там два очень похожих кода создания потока, но в втором аргументы наоборот. Но может быть так и задумано.

Comment: Я думал в мютекс нужно заворачивать лишь области, где пишется. Нужно ли тогда так же каждый вывод через printf в мютекс заворачивать? Это ведь тоже чтение. На счет чтения в if: нужно ли тогда весь  if-блок блокировать с помощью мютекса? На счет аргументов во втором блоке - поправил. Спасибо. Т.е я могу с помощью `memcpy`создать новый массив и передать ссылку на него в поток, я правильно понял?

Comment: в данном случае теоретически проблем с чтением не должно возникать - int может быть записан одной инструкцией. А вот если структура чуть сложнее, то она  может читаться, пока в другом месте пишут и быть в несогласованном состоянии. А это печаль. Но завернуть все в мютекс - это также перебор. **Т.е я могу с помощью memcpy** - да там два int скопировать.

Comment: Использование копий решило проблему. А можно ли было решить данную задачу более элегантно, при условии, что оба параметра все равно нужно передавать?

Comment: а что Вы понимаете под словами "более элегантно"?

Comment: Всегда есть более изощеренный способ решить проблему. Мне мое решение почему-то не нравится и просто интересно, как можно было бы ту же задачу решить другим путем

Comment: Можно использовать атомики или семафоры. Или просто не создавать потоки.