# Создание дерева потоков

Tags: c, многопоточность, posix

Я новичек в pthread. В учебных целях я написал программу, которая должна создавать дерево потоков(что-то на подобие `fork()`). Мой код работает, создает дерево вроде как правильно. Но единственный минус - id потоков повторяются. Они не уникальны и я не совсем понимаю почему, ведь я для каждого потока создаю массив аргументов, а переменную `threads_counter`(которую можно как id для процессов использовать) защищаю с помощью мютекса. В результате каждый поток имеет свои аргументы. Если раскомментировать `printf()` перед `pthread_create()`, то можно увидеть, что в качестве аргументов потоки получают уникальный id, но в потоке выводится на экран совершенно другое.
Вместо вывода:

```
Hello, my ID is 1. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 2. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 3. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 4. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
```

я получаю следующее:

```
Hello, my ID is 3. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 3. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 3. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
Hello, my ID is 3. My parent id is 0. I'll create 2 child
```

Так же буду очень благодарен, если кто-то объяснит, зачем нужно защищать критические зоны для чтения и как это делать например в блоке if.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 21

pthread_mutex_t threads_count_mutex;
int threads_count = 0;
int divisor = 2;

void *CreateThreadTree(void *args) {

    int* this_thread_arg = (int*) args;

        // Parse args
    int children_count = this_thread_arg[0];
    int this_thread_id = this_thread_arg[1];
    int parent_thread_id = this_thread_arg[2];

    int i = 0;
    pthread_t threads[children_count];

    printf("Hello, my ID is %d. My parent id is %d. I'll create %d child\n", this_thread_id, parent_thread_id, children_count);


    for (i = 0; i < children_count; i++) {
        if (threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
            int new_thread_args[3];

            pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);
                new_thread_args[1] = threads_count++;    // Id of the next
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex);

            new_thread_args[0] = children_count / divisor;
            new_thread_args[2] = this_thread_arg[1];


                // List next thread args
            //printf("Next thread params [%d][%d][%d]\n", new_thread_args[0], new_thread_args[1], new_thread_args[2]);
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, CreateThreadTree, new_thread_args);

        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < children_count; i++) 
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    printf("t%d: I'm done. Bye...\n", this_thread_arg[1]);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t start_thread = NULL;
    int start_thread_args[3];

        // Children count
    start_thread_args[0] = 4;
        // ID of this Thread
    start_thread_args[1] = 0;

        // ID of Parent Thread
    start_thread_args[2] = -1;

    pthread_mutex_init(&threads_count_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&start_thread, NULL, CreateThreadTree, start_thread_args);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: так уже почти все разобрали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748035/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0?rq=1

Comment: В прошлый раз я по Вашему совету просто создавал копии(т.е новые аргументы для каждого потока). В этот раз по сути(в ìf`-блоке создается новая инстанция для следующего потока) тоже самое, но все равно вывод отличается...

Comment: Вы внутри цикла создаете **локальную переменную** new_thread_args и передаете на нее ссылку. При следующем проходе цикла получается так, что переменная хоть вроде как новая, но создается скорее всего по тому же адресу. (потому что стек). Вот и получается, что все треды, которые создаются внутри цикла, по факту имееют одну и ту же ссылку на new_thread_args

Comment: Но если создание инстанции вынести за предел цикла, то цикл постоянно будет оперировать с одной и той же ссылкой, верно?

Comment: А что если попробовать вместо массива аргументов использовать struct...

Comment: Структура не поможет. В любом случае можно распечатать значение адреса и убедиться самостоятельно

Comment: Да, сылка действительно имеет один и тот же адрес в цикле(спасибо за идею, это еще один интересный способ понять, что именно не так работает) . Т.е. выходит, что никак нельзя заставить компилятор создавать новые ссылки в цикле?

Comment: Немного подумав, пришел к выводу, что можно использовать malloc. Тогда в цикле будут создаваться указатели с разными адрессами. Попробую переписать код используя malloc для создания новых инстанций. Теоретически должно помочь. Вопрос лишь в том, насколько хороший это подход для решения задачи...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При моем подходе в цикле не создается каждый раз новый массив, в нем существует лишь одна и та же ссылка(огромное спасибо господину **KoVadim** за подсказку этого ньюанса), а нужно чтоб при каждом проходе цикла создавалась новая ссылка(инстанция) на аргументы для нового потока. Изменил код так, чтоб при каждом проходе цикла генерировалась новая область в памяти с помощью `malloc()`.
Достаточно было в цикле функции заменить:

```
int new_thread_args[3];
```

на

```
int *new_thread_args = NULL;
new_thread_args = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```